# PHP Exec Does not Launch Application

Tags: php, exec

I'm attempting to run an application - more specifically a Source Dedicated Server - through a web-interface. I am doing this using the following code:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir("[PATH]");
$tmp = exec("srcds -console -game tf +map ctf_2fort");
chdir($old_path);
```

Unfortunately, the site hangs, and is never loaded. Running the same exact command through the command prompt works perfectly, running `exec("echo %cd%")` outputs the correct path, I can run other things (such as a sample .bat that simply echoes `%time%`) from the folder, so on and so forth.

I have been able to make the site load by redirecting stdout to `/dev/null/` (replacing the `$tmp =` line with the following:)

```
$tmp = exec("srcds -console -game tf +map ctf_2fort > /dev/null");
```

While this allows the site to load, the application is never run (and the process doesn't appear in the task manager).

I've tried outputting to a file, but this simply outputs two lines, the first one saying `Using breakpad minidump system`, the second one empty. It also doesn't launch the application.

```
$tmp = exec("srcds -console -game tf +map ctf_2fort > tmp.txt");
```

I'm at loss as to what I should do - I'm fairly new to PHP, so if there's anything obvious I'm missing, please do say so.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `2>&1` to the command. You can also specify if you want each line of the output from what happened to be displayed as an array, like so:

```
$tmp = exec("srcds -console -game tf +map ctf_2fort 2>&1", $what_happened);
print_r($what_happened);
```

If safe mode is on, you might run into some problems though... If the above suggestion doesn't work for you, you might also check out the [system()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and/or [passthru()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) commands.

Comment: Unfortunately those have the same problem as previously; the page never loads. Writing the output to a variable simply returns a 0-length array (when redirecting stdout, as it otherwise won't start, so it's fairly obvious that the output is null)